# Tkinter window doesnt close clicking the "X"-Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning to handle the tkinter package in the Python programming language in order to create GUIs.

Many things work just fine, but often times after creating a tkinter window it won´t close clicking the "X"-Button. Then I have to close it with the task manager and after doing this the console of my Python-IDE spyder gives out that the kernel died ("kernel died, restarting").

I searched for this topic on the internet and in this forum but couldn´t find an answer fitting to my problem. Below there is a little code example producing a window which doesn´t close pressing the "X"-Button on my computer.

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Pong")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas=Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.config(bg = "white")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_line(250,0,250,400, fill = "white")
tk.update()
```

Comment: Add tk.mainloop() on the last line

Comment: Adding tk.mainloop() worked. Thank you! Do you know the reason, why tk.update() led to complications? I am a bit confused, because I wrote one program without any mainloop()-statement and it worked too.

Comment: I think this is an ipython issue, I can't reproduce this with IDLE or the python interpreter. As Ninad says, use .mainloop()

Comment: Ok, thank you two. :)